# Pairing Cohomology with Homology on pg.510 in "Modern classical homotopy theory".

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, functors

Here is the paragraph in the book:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- I do not understand why if $\alpha \in \widetilde{H}_{n}(X; B),$ then it should be represented by the given map below. Could anyone explain this to me, please?

2-Is the function defined in the last line above is what is called **Cap product**?

Comment: Question $1)$ is Problem 22.24 in the book. $2)$ Yes, this is the cap product.

Comment: How can I prove 22.24? @Tyrone

Comment: Start with the Freudenthal Theorem. You should assume that $X$ is well-pointed. You also have the material in $\S$ 18.

Comment: Why do I need the material on section 18? or do you mean section 17?@Tyrone

Comment: You want to be able to calculate the connectivity of $X\wedge \Sigma K(G,t)\rightarrow X\wedge K(G,t+1)$.